# Show the sequence uniformly converge to null function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, functional-inequalities

**Problem*: If $f_0$ is a continuous function in $[0,a]$, $a>0$, show that the sequence $\{f_k\}$ (on that same interval) defined the recursive relatio n$f_k(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^x f_{k-1}(t)dt$ converges uniformly to the null function.*

Some osbervations I could figure out, are:

- If $f_0$ is continuos, integrating it will result in a continuous fuction.
- I'm not sure about this one, I think we need $f_k\geq 0,$ but every term of the sequence is bounded by $\int_0^x f_{k-1}(t)dt\leq\int_0^a f_k(t)dt$, being the last one a number.

I also tried to take $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sup\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f_k(x)-f(x)|$ as if it goes to $0$ thesis is true.

When I tried to take the pointwise convergence, I write $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\int_0^x f_{k-1}(t)dt$.

There might by way using derivatives and theoremes related to them and uniformly convergence, but couldn't figure it out.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Prove by induction that $|f_k(x)| \leq M\frac {x^{k}} {k!}$ where $M=\sup |f(t)|$. This question has appeared mayt times earlier.